# RE: JButton action listener is restarting entire program

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am writing a GUI, and I have made custom buttons using null layouts, however whenever I am adding a action listener each time the button is pressed it is reloading the entire image, making it look different, is it possible to use an action listener several times without necessarily doing a new one?

Comment: > "Is it possible to use an action listener several times without necessarily doing a new one?" 

Yes, absolutely.  Your code is doing something wrong, what it is is impossible to say without code.

Comment: "I have made custom buttons using **null layouts,** .." 10:1 your next question will be WTE "Why is my UI layout broken?".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a new `ActionListener` every time you want to handle an action. Just add one and it will keep working, everytime the button is pressed the `actionPerformed` method is called.. and I actually don't get why you add another one everytime (they will coexist so the actionPerformed is invoked many times)